# What causes a negative voltage dip on the collector of common emitter NPN circuit at turn-off?

Tags: pullup, pnp, common-emitter

Circuit diagram:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSKHTZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Observed waveforms:

(Yellow: 3.3V square wave in, Magenta: Collector output)

[image]

When the input square wave goes low and the transistor is supposed to turn off (thus, collector pulled high through R2,) we first observe a small negative dip on the collector, lasting about 1500ns, before it starts being pulled high.

What causes this? How can I mitigate it?

I'm working on a circuit where the open collector output on a comparator exhibits the same behavior.  This dip in the wrong direction messes up my hysteresis causing the output to bounce.

Comment: Since you driving bjt very hard (base even harder then collector) you put transistor into deep saturation. It’s “painful” to get transistor from this state back to cut-off.

Comment: If you need to drive very fast most of designers put schottky between base and collector to bjt not reach saturation.

Comment: It’s called “Baker clamp”. Another option is connect a small capacitor (like 100pF) parallel to base resistor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a caused by the reverse recovery of the base emitter junction. The high base current causes a large build up of minority carriers, in the base region, that must be removed before the collector voltage can rise.

The delay cannot be eliminated but it can be reduced. This always slows down turn-off when deep in saturation. It is better to use the minimum base current required to maintain saturation reliably.

The collector current is only ~0.33 mA in saturation. The base current is 10 times at 3.3mA. It should be no more than 0.033 mA. Ic/Ib = 10. Data sheets often characterize at this ratio.

This can be reduced more, but temperature or transient effects must be considered.

Comment: I've swapped the resistors around so base current is ~10x less then collector current and that solves the problem. So the cause is excessive base current. In the case of my open collector comparator I've no control over the base current but lowering the resistor values on the collector side by a factor 10, increasing collector current by the same ratio, solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Storage time and Ccb are two possibilities, but I'm inclined to think it's actually emitter resistance, or other stray resistance you're not showing [likely not aware of, e.g. breadboard with poor connections etc.].

The excessive base current seems the most likely route for mitigation; even 100k base resistor would be low for the load shown. Whether this impacts switching speed, is up to you.

Here is a quick breadboarding:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUSE8K.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Ch1 is timing reference, Ch2 is base voltage `VB`, Ch3 is collector voltage `VC`.  DUT was a JAN2N1711 medium-power transistor, giving a rather long storage time around 3µs.

The same test with a 2N3904 (very similar to BC547, may indeed even be identical from several manufacturers) gives a more reasonable 390ns storage time.

Where the emitter resistance R3 has come from, I don't know, but whether on board, or a poor-performing or defective transistor, it seems a plausible explanation at this time.

@G36 measured a real BC546:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXcwm.png]

Comment: I actually think you are right to suggest the emitter resistance (perhaps stray.) TR and TF and CJC parameters are an unavoidable part of it but alone they would all have some `shape` to them. The flatness shown in the scope image says `emitter resistance` loudly. The duration is a bit long, though. So I'm thinking a lot of stray capacitance across BC, as well. I'm having a hard time imagining 1500 ns. That sure eliminates storage time as the issue. Anyway, I think you are right.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see that BC547 should have such long storage time; and, testing the extremely similar 2N3904, it indeed has little. I do however see PBSS4540X, 2N2102 and JAN2N1711 giving exceptionally long storage (~3us).

Comment: I tested BC548B and they indeed has a storage time around 1.5μs.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXcwm.png

Comment: @G36 Thanks, fascinating!

Comment: I've swapped the resistors around so base current is ~10x less then collector current and that solves the problem. I've also scoped the emitter and it does not move. So it's completely related to excessive base current.